# Require UTF-8 php file

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, include, require

I'm experiencing very strange problem regarding encoding PHP files in UTF-8. For example, I have two files: index.php and require.php. In index.php files I have this code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<?php
require 'require.php';
?>
<body>
<a></a>
</body>
</html>
```

In require.php I only have empty PHP tags

```
<?php

?>
```

When I open index.php and use Chrome's Element Inspector to see the output HTML I get this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
"
"
<a></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the two strange quote marks at the begining of body. If I remove the require statement from PHP code or simply remove a tags they dissapear. What's even stranger is that if I echo something out in require.php file it gets outputed between those two quotes.
The problem goes away if I change encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI in require.php

I've been searching for answer for hours and did not found single person who has same problem.

Comment: What does [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) say about the encoding index.php and require.php ? Are they both encoded to UTF-8?

Comment: Use a hexeditor and show us the actual contents, not the visualization of Chromes view source or whatever.

Comment: Standard guess: you have a BOM. Search for that keyword.

Comment: Yes, when I changed encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-8 without BOM it started working fine. Thanks!

Comment: I HAD THE EXACTLY SAME PROBLEM . :)

Answer (score 1):

Try add `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in index.php, and remove the ending '?>' from require.php.

Answer (score 1):

Made worse after adding the header. Although, converting the file to UFT-8 Without BOM is worked for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a plaintext file, you will need this...

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    print('中文。');
?>
```

For sending HTML, you'll need to change the header's "text/plain" to "text/html".